# Is there a way to compress a MySQL column where values repeat very often?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a InnoDB table with a VARCHAR column, with tens of thousands instances of the same text under it. Is there a way to compact it on-the-fly in order to save space? Is some kind of INDEX enough?

---

Can't InnoDB see that the values are the same, and use less space by internally assigning them some ID or whatever?

Comment: Would you please elaborate the situation, and/or give an example? ALso, what do you mean by "under it"? Is there repeated text IN the varchar field, or is there many database entries with the same content in that varchar?

Comment: If you're finding same text repeating many times then why not normalize the schema by creating second table to store unique values and use foreign key constraint?

Comment: I would rather not have to make another call just for this one column

Comment: @user129013 Minimizing data storasge does always require additional operations, be it on your application logic or inside DB logic.

A simple INNER JOIN / NATURL JOIN is not a very expensive operation for the DB engine to perform.

Answer (score 2):

If the task is as simple as it seems, then what you are looking for is normalisation.

In simple terms, what you have to do is make this column contain Foreign Keys to another table, which has the values for this table. Now, store newer values in the other table, and when a value previously exists you do not need to make another entry for that in the table. Form this relation between the tables and in your original table a huge amount of space will be saved.

I suggest you to read up about redundancies and normalisation.

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL ENUM data type. It stores the values as indexes, but upon select you see the text value.

Here is the documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Cons are that not all databases support ENUM type so you may find that as a problem if some day you decide to switch databases.

There also some other limitations pointed here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html#enum-limits

Comment: Another problem is to add values. This would require an `ALTER TABLE` which is an expensive operation and should never be something that is part of regular program flow.